# When a promise-based modal closes, what is a good pattern for handling subsequent errors?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Say you have an API for producing a modal that asks the user for a value, and the call to create that modal returns a promise that either resolves to the value given, or rejects if the modal is closed/cancelled. Example:

```
prompt("Enter a value.").then(val => { }).catch(() => { /* closed */ });
```

The suggested pattern I have seen for dealing with a rejected promise for a closed modal is to just add a `catch` statement with a "no operation" lambda like the one you see above. The problem with this is that, if you want to build onto the promise chain when the modal *is* successful, then any errors in subsequent logic will also fail silently due to the "no operation" lambda:

```
prompt("Enter a value.")
  .then(val => { /* logic that could throw an error */ })
  .then(() => { /* method that may return another promise */ })
  .catch(() => { }) // Silent fail
  .then(() => { /* logic after modal */ })
```

An obvious solution would just be to move the `then` statements after the "no operation" catch, and catch them with new statements, but remember that these blocks must only execute if the modal is successful, and therefore can't go after the above `catch` statement.

What would you do?

Comment: I'd say the pending state of a promise is most appropriate to express a modal-closed-event, i.e. just leave the promise pending in this case.

Comment: How do you pass on control and leave the promise pending?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented something similar recently as well, and my approach was that the modal would return `undefined` if it was closed or cancelled. I try to reserve `catch()` for "true" errors.

However, you can also remember that you can `throw` anything, not just `Error`s. So, alternately, you can `throw` something that lets you recognize that the modal was closed, and do nothing in that case; otherwise, proceed to handle the exception.

```
prompt.CLOSE_SIGNAL = Symbol('prompt.CLOSE_SIGNAL');

prompt('Enter a value.')
.then(/* ... */)
.catch(ex => {
    if (ex === prompt.CLOSE_SIGNAL) return;

    // Otherwise:
    console.error('Error from modal:', ex);
});
```

Comment: I went with something like this too. In the modal, I used a `reject("closed")` and pivoted on that in the eventual `catch` statement. It's a bit derpy since there is some implied state, but it sure does work.